# How do I overlap two images in one DIV?

Tags: html, image, css, block, overlap

How do I overlap two images in one DIV?  I have these two images, which I'd like to stack one on top of the other

```
    <div id="personImgDiv">
<img id="scaleImg" src="http://hddfhm.com/images/clipart-110-scale-2.gif" />
<img id="personImg" src="http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/simpsons/images/6/69/The_simpsons_ralph_wiggum-1-.png/revision/latest?cb=20141124210636" />

</div>
```

I thought this CSS would do it ...

```
#scaleImg {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}


#personImg {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
```

But it isn't.  Here's the Fiddle that demonstrates my problem -- https://jsfiddle.net/vksLv6ew/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this behaviour, the *container* element should be *relative* and the children must be *absolute*.

I.e. the children will have absolute positioning relative to the container. Here is the corresponding style:

```css
#container {
    position: relative;
}

#container img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <img src="http://hddfhm.com/images/clipart-110-scale-2.gif" />
    <img src="http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/simpsons/images/6/69/The_simpsons_ralph_wiggum-1-.png/revision/latest?cb=20141124210636" />
</div>
```

Fiddle to play with: https://jsfiddle.net/npsquc6g/

Answer (score 0):

```
#personImgDiv {
    position: relative; /* this is the most important bit*/
}
#scaleImg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
#personImg {
    position: relative; /* only set this if you want this image to overlap the other, otherwise don't */
}
```